# Terraform - Get the Primary Static Website Endpoint of a Storage account

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-storage-account, azure-front-door

I want to deploy an Azure Front Door with a backend linked to the Static Website of a Storage Account. If I use Azure Portal there's no problem, but I can't get how to retrieve the Primary Static Website's Endpoint ?

Moreover, the Primary Endpoint goes out like `https://saprodgamingfiles.z6.web.core.windows.net/` but for the backend host name we want `saprodgamingfiles.z6.web.core.windows.net`.

How to automate the creation of the Front Door backend related to the Storage Account's Static Website Primary Endpoint ?

---

**Synthesis**

I want to automate the following `host_header` and `address` from the Azure Front Door Terraform config...

```
backend {
     host_header = "saprodgamingfiles.z6.web.core.windows.net"
     address     = "saprodgamingfiles.z6.web.core.windows.net"
     http_port   = 80
     https_port  = 443
     priority    = 1
     weight      = 50
}
```

... related to the static website created as such with the Storage Account :

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "saprodgamingfiles" {
    name                = var.sa_name1
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg-prod-gaming.name

    # etc...

    # THIS : Pre-requisite for Azure Front Door
    static_website {}
}
```

I'm new to Terraform & Azure, but I searched a lot and I couldn't find a satisfying solution to my problem. I'm surprised it's not raised as much, maybe I'm just missing something ?

Best

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [primary_web_host](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_account#primary_web_host) in the backend,

[image]

Output the value  of

```
output "primary_web_host" {
    value = data.azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_web_host
}
```

You will see

[image]

So the backend will like this:

```
backend {
     host_header = azurerm_storage_account.saprodgamingfiles.primary_web_host
     address     = azurerm_storage_account.saprodgamingfiles.primary_web_host
     http_port   = 80
     https_port  = 443
     priority    = 1
     weight      = 50
}
```